# Finding max in numpy skipping some rows and column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to find the max row and column index in a numpy matrix. But it not be in the a set of rows or columns. Thus, it should skip those rows and columns while computing the max.

**Example:**

```
# finding max in numpy matrix 
[row,col] = np.where(mat == mat.max())
```

But it should skip rows removed_rows=[] and columns  columns_rows=[]

I don't want to  create a new sub matrix for the computation.

Comment: Would the array/matrix have negative numbers?

Comment: @Divakar No, it contains only non-negative numbers.

Comment: Would it be okay to change the input array?

Comment: Are the removed rows and columns always *contiguous*? [2,3,4] not [2,4,6]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `a` be the input array, `rows_rem` and `cols_rem` be the rows and column indices to be skipped respectively. We would have an approach using masking, like so -

```
m,n = a.shape
d0,d1 = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
a_masked = a*~(np.in1d(d0,rows_rem)[:,None] | np.in1d(d1,cols_rem))
max_row, max_col = np.where(a_masked == a_masked.max())
```

Sample run -

```
In [204]: # Inputs
     ...: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,5))
     ...: rows_rem = [1,3]
     ...: cols_rem = [1,2,4]
     ...: 

In [205]: a
Out[205]: 
array([[36, 51, 72, 18, 31],
       [78, 42, 12, 71, 72],
       [38, 46, 42, 67, 12],
       [87, 56, 76, 14, 21]])

In [206]: a_masked
Out[206]: 
array([[64,  0,  0, 90,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [17,  0,  0, 40,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

In [207]: max_row, max_col
Out[207]: (array([0]), array([3]))
```

Please note that if there's more than one element with the same max value, we would have all of those in the output. So, if you want any or the first of those, we can use `argmax`, like so -

```
max_row, max_col = np.unravel_index(a_masked.argmax(),a.shape)
```

Comment: Any way to do via slicing, skipping those rows and columns.

Comment: Please check the edit in the question. It gives elements not in the matrix itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_rows = [2,3]
remove_cols = [0,1]

a = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,5))

>>> a
array([[60, 86, 89, 66, 20],
       [77, 86, 78, 90, 44],
       [68, 57, 83, 48, 25],
       [30, 81, 42, 11, 63]])
>>>
```

Get the row and column indices that you are interested in by filtering out the indices you want removed:

```
r, c = a.shape
r = [x for x in range(r) if x not in remove_rows]
c = [x for x in range(c) if x not in remove_cols]

>>> r,c
([0, 1], [2, 3, 4])
>>>
```

Now `r` and `c` can be used for [integer indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), [numpy.ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) helps with this.

```
>>> a[np.ix_(r,c)]
array([[89, 66, 20],
       [78, 90, 44]])
>>>
```

Tack on ndarray.max() to get the max value:

```
>>> a[np.ix_(r,c)].max()
90
>>>
```

Finally, use numpy.where to find where it is in the original array:

```
>>> row, col = np.where(a == a[np.ix_(r,c)].max())
>>> row, col
(array([1]), array([3]))
>>>
```

---

This method will also work if removing *non-sequential* rows or columns.
For example:

```
remove_rows = [0,3]
remove_cols = [1,4]
```

Comment: The same thing happens with your answer for the edit. It gives elements not in the matrix itself. Please check with `a=np.array([[ 11.,   1.],[  1.,   5.],[  1.,  11.]])`.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, I didn't understand: what/how do you want me to check ```a=np.array([[ 11., 1.],[ 1., 5.],[ 1., 11.]])```?